# CSS: Keeping the main content div centered when the div to the right of it is Adblocked

Tags: css, alignment, adblock

I've got two divs, the left one holds my content, the right one holds an ad. They're both set to inline-block, and they're in a wrapper div with text-align: center set to keep them centered. This way in the event that the ad div is blocked, the content div is centered correctly on its own.

The problem occurs once I use margin/padding to put a gap in between the divs. I need this so that my ad isn't 1px away from my content. But this padding is retained when the ad is blocked, which means that the main content div is shifted to the left by half this padding amount.

I've tried padding-left and margin-left in the right div, and padding-right and margin-right in the left div. It looks like adblock is setting the div width and height to 0 to hide it, so the padding remains.

All help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try putting the margin/padding on the content of the div (the `img` I guess) instead of the div itself. That's what adblock is likely removing from the DOM, not the `div` container, so when it is gone from the DOM its styles should go with it.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist this only works if the divs do not have a specified width. It's hard to tell without seeing any code. As always....

Comment: @alpipego I was assuming they did not given what he said about trying to provide "correct centering" for the content div when the ad isn't there. This leads me to believe the ad div's width is given by its content. Code would be nice, though. :)

Comment: I assumed it was something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XAVt5/2/ but let's wait for some code from the OP.

Comment: That works great Two-Bit Alchemist, thank you! It's google ad code and there's a line right in there for CSS, I just added the margin-left in there :)

Comment: Converted to answer so you have something you can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should the margin/padding you want on the ad itself (I am guessing an `img`) rather than its enclosing `div` container. This is because AdBlock will remove the `img` (but not its parent `div`) from the DOM, taking its styles along with it.